# Find what pages IE is fetching similar to console in firebug?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Firebug Lite bookmarklet is no help here, on half the pages it doesn't even show up.

What I need is basically this: [image: XMLhttprequests]

to show what IE is connecting to, because my application is working fine in firefox and chrome, but in an enterprise/corporate environment, I have to get it working with IE as well, and it's not working there.

Any ideas of how I can get something similar just to see what the page is trying to (or not trying to) connect to? I'm using IE8 for this (on an windows XP machine, can't use IE9)

Comment: [http proxy for debugging purposes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831450/http-proxy-for-debugging-purposes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With IE9 I'd use the built-in developer tools, but for IE8, try [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2). It's basically an HTTP proxy that lets you inspect, modify and create HTTP requests.

Comment: Looks promising, installing now.

Comment: Works great, now I just have to figure out why my autocomplete script isn't even starting in IE but working fine in the others, and why it's doing a search by name but will do a search with numbers (phone or location). It has to be something that didn't move properly, checking what the dev version is using compared to QA with this. Thanks!